# Inserting Values Into Table Using Psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to insert values into my table using psycopg2. My insert query has the column name and i am using the .format method to insert the variable into the values. The error i am getting is below...it seems that its using the "test" string from my email as a column. When i remove the email column and just leave account_number it is inserting only partial random numbers and not '123456789'... I am not sure why?

I am getting an error:

```
"    VALUES ({},{})""".format(account2, email2))
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: missing FROM-clause entry for table 
"test"
LINE 2:             VALUES (123456789,test@example.com)
```

I have tried to use "%" format as well to see if its my .format way of inserting values into the query but that did not work either.

```
                    elif extrareadayday_date in extrareaddays:
                        accounts_sheet = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\bxt058y\\PycharmProjects\\MSIT501\\MSIT\\sumbaccounts.xlsx",
                                                       sheet_name=0)
                        df = DataFrame(accounts_sheet)
                        email_address2 = df[df['cycle_day'] == current_cycle_day].email_address_test
                        account_numbers2 = df[df['cycle_day'] == current_cycle_day].account_number
                        email_address3 = df[df['cycle_day'] == current_cycle_day2].email_address_test
                        account_numbers3 = df[df['cycle_day'] == current_cycle_day2].account_number
                        for account2, email2 in zip(account_numbers2, email_address2):
                            to_file(sumbstatementfilepath, account2, 'N - NOT BILLED', 'SUMB_Statement_{}.txt'.format(account2.strip()), email2)
                            print(account2)
                            extra_read_day_confirmation_email()
                            cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sumb_email_conf (account_number, email_address)
                            VALUES ({},{})""".format(account2, email2))
                        for account3, email3 in zip(account_numbers3, email_address3):
                            to_file(sumbstatementfilepathreadday, account3, 'N - NOT BILLED', 'SUMB_Statement_{}.txt'.format(account3.strip()),
                                    email3)
                            print(account3)
                            extra_read_day_confirmation_email2()
                            cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sumb_email_conf (account_number,email_address)
                                        VALUES ({},{})""".format(account3, email3))
                            connection.commit()
```

Comment: instead of executing the insert string directly, try putting it in a variable and printing it before execution. That way you can see what's getting executed and what the problem might be

Comment: In order for your execute to work you would need to do this `...VALUES ('{}','{}')""".format(account3, email3))`, HOWEVER you should NEVER do that.  `%s` tokenizes and prevents sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

For psycopg2 formatting, you can try using the mogify method. 
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify

Example wrt your question:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO sumb_email_conf (account_number,email_address VALUES (%s, %s)"
query = cursor.mogrify(SQL, account3, email3)
cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Can you add some more details to the answer rather than just giving a link? A link can be given as a comment, but add some more relevant details for the answer to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the string in the SQL if you use python formatting:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sumb_email_conf (account_number, email_address)
                            VALUES ({},'{}')""".format(account2, email2))
```

However, it is probably better to have the database API do it:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sumb_email_conf (account_number, email_address)
                            VALUES (%s,%s)""", [account2, email2])
```